# How can I format the drive where ubuntu is installed without disturbing the bootloader?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I am using dual-boot. Windows 7 along with Ubuntu 13.04. Windows 7 is installed on drive `C:\` while Ubuntu is installed on drive `J:\`.

My HDD is 500GB. My laptop came with Windows 7. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 later. After installing Ubuntu my bootloader is changed. Now I see the boot screen which is provided by Ubuntu.

As first option of the list I see Ubuntu. Windows comes at the bottom of the list. However now I am going to install Ubuntu 14.04 on drive `J:\`. It will be a fresh installation.

Before installing Ubuntu 14.04 I just want to format drive `J:\` where old Ubuntu 13.04 is installed. Now my question is if I format drive `J:\` from Windows 7 will I face problems to boot next time?

Can I format drive `J:\` without disturbing the existing boot loader?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10?

Comment: @A.B. Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @user68186 great info. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys I have installed my Ubuntu 14 just now. It works smoothly. :))))  What I did is I am listing here. It might help others who wants to know solution of same problem...

1. I created a USB boot device burning the ubuntu ISO into it.
2. Then I booted from the USB.
3. After it when partitioning options came I just selected my old partition where Ubuntu 13 was installed and just deleted the partition. After deletion of the partition I just installed the Ubuntu 14 on same partition.

Thats all. Now when I restart my PC I see same boot loader from where I can login to both my Windows 7 and new Ubuntu 14. Simple!! :)

Comment: Great! congratulations!! Now you can click on the gray check mark on the left of the answer that you think is the best answer. This will help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

## It sounds like you have an WUBI install of Ubuntu 13.04.

See the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) for more information about WUBI.

**WUBI is not being developed and is not supported anymore.** Therefore this is the best time for you to move from WUBI to full install.

A full install of Ubuntu needs two partitions that Windows do not understand. (a) First, a root partition, also called a `/` partition in the `ext4` format. (b) a Swap partition in its own format. This should not be a problem unless you already have four primary partitions (the maximum possible) in your computer.

## Steps for removing WUBI Ubuntu 13.04 and installing Ubuntu 14.04 in its own partitions.

1. Backup all your files both in Windows and Ubuntu. You never know what can go wrong.
2. Uninstall Ubuntu 13.04 from within Windows using the Add-Remove program.
3. Using the Windows default partition management utility, delete `J:\` drive and keep the area unformatted.
4. Boot from live DVD/USB of Ubuntu 14.04 and install from there. The installation process should find the unallocated empty space where `J:\` was and create its own partitions there and install the GRUB boot loader at the proper place.

For more information see [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

If you don't have an WUBI install, you can go straight to step 4 above. Ubuntu 14.04 installation process will see that you have 13.04 installed already and offer to replace it with the new version.

Hope this helps